# Laravel Set tab active in foreach

Tags: css, angularjs, laravel

how do i set a tab page class 'active' in a dynamical created list?

i have a link 'toon alle' where i show all my records, but when ik click a link i display a different view. but the active tab remains on my first link.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills sort-source" data-sort-id="portfolio" data-option-key="filter">
    <li data-option-value="*" class="active">
        <a href="#" ng-click="getAllRequests(1)">Toon alle</a>
    </li>
    @foreach ($Categories as $categorie)
        <li data-option-value=".{{$categorie->nameN}}" class="">
            <a href="#" ng-click="getRequests({{$categorie->id}})"
               data-id="{{$categorie->id}}">{{$categorie->nameN}}
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: how about `class="{{ $categorie->id == $activeCategoryId ? 'active' : '' }}"`?

Comment: Where do you declare the variable $activeCategoryId?

Comment: I don't know how you define which category to show. You should declare the variable in your controller and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using a custom `facade` or a `HTML macro` if you are using `laravel 4`.
This example assumes you are using named routes.

You can also change `route($route)` with `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()`

## For the macro in laravel 4

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Active state HTML Macro
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Tests a route against the current URL for active state
| If true, returns 'active' for class name
| Usage: HTML::activeState('named.route')
|
*/
    HTML::macro('activeState', function ($route,$arguments=NULL,$class='active')
    {
          return strpos(Request::url(), route($route,$arguments)) !== false ? $class : '';
    });
```

For the facade(If you don't know what a facade is & how to create one [read here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades)

## Facade Accessor

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
class activeState extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'activeState '; }

}
```

## Facade Main Class

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class activeState {

    public function activeState($route,$arguments=NULL,$class='active')
    {

     return strpos(Request::url(), route($route,$arguments)) !== false ? $class : '';

    }

}
```

## Facade Service Provider

```
App::bind('activeState ', function()
{
    return new App\Helpers\activeState ;
});
```

Then add the new provider/alias laravel configuration files.

Inside your views 

`<li class="{{activeState::activeState('route.name')}}">This is an li item</li>`